# How to share DataStore between two different rule unit in a BPMN process with Drools 8?

Tags: java, quarkus, drools, bpmn, kogito

Context : I am migrating my Java/DRL project from Drools 7 to Drools 8.

To do this I am using the new Rule Unit style combined with kogito/quarkus recommended by Drools. I am trying to figure out how one can achieve to do this :

> DataSources can be shared across different units, providing a
> coordination mechanism between them. (source -> [sharing_dataSource](https://docs.drools.org/8.39.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/KIE/index.html#rule-unit-api_packaging-deploying) )

Let's say I have two Rule Unit A and B such as :

*Start -> A -> B -> End*

Then I should define two Java Class **AUnit** and **BUnit** implementing RuleUnitData. Both class have their owns DataStore fields standing for the entry-point of each rule unit.

I don't understand how it is possible to define a shared DataStore between my two RuleUnits since a DataStore should be declared in either one or the other one ... But maybe I'm getting wrong on something.

I have actually no idea how to do this.

Comment: I'm probably not understanding your question, but you can declare the same DataStore in multiple different rule units and then pass the same DataStore instance to all of them at creation time or even set it at a later stage. What am I missing?

Comment: @MarioFusco, let me clarify : with Drools 7, the Working Memory was persistent through ALL the BPMN process. That was very useful because I could declare a variable that was readable and writable through all the process.

With drools 8 and the RuleUnit style, it seems that every RuleUnit has it own Working Memory, which means there is no more a persistent memory area through the whole workflow.

Seems like the only way to reproduce the behaviour is to declare a process variable in the bpmn and initialize every DataStore in the RuleUnit with it, but it's not as simple as what I had before.

Comment: Hi @Chaudassin, 
maybe another way to phrase it :  is there a way to share a set of objets between BPMN tasks without having to declare them explicitely in a Java Holder object like RuleUnit ?

The "insert" keyword authorized that in a way in previous drools version as the wm info (with these anonymous "new" objets inserted) was shared among different DRL tasks.

So some objects in the WM were transient to process/rules and unknown  to outside world. 

see also :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444305/how-does-drl-key-insert-in-rule-conditions-works-with-ruleunit-in-drools